# Reactjs Showing Sidebar Menu with animation

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations, keyframe

I need some insight pls.
I tried to build a sidebar menu with an animation that will show from left -100% to 100% fullscreen when state is true and close from 100% fullscreen to left -100% when the state is false.

The animation works when the state is true but the animation doesn't work when closing the sidebar menu.

Btw if there's a better approach for this pattern please let me know. Thank you in advance !

```
const PhoneNavigation = ({ handleClose, open }) => {
  return (
    <nav className={open ? "show_side_bar" : "close_side_bar"}>
      <span onClick={handleClose}>X</span>
      <ul>
        <li className="subMenu navItem">
          <a href="/">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li className="navItem">
          <a href="/">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li className="navItem">
          <a href="/">Mission</a>
        </li>
        <li className="subMenu navItem">
          <a href="/">About us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default PhoneNavigation;
```

### // STYLING SHEET

```
.show_side_bar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: brown;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  animation: showMenu 2s;
}

.close_side_bar {
  animation: showMenu 2s reverse;
}

@keyframes showMenu {
  from {
    left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    left: 0%;
  }
}
```

Comment: For the solution you need create a reverse animation in the `close_side_bar` class. Because if the animation is inside `show_side_bar` it's break after switching to second class.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work on closing the sidebar because animations are applied only on the entry of an element. Instead, you can use transition like this :

```
const PhoneNavigation = ({ handleClose, open }) => {
  return (
    // when open is true, there will be an additional class show_side_bar
    <nav className={open ? "show_side_bar side_bar" : "side_bar"}>
      <span onClick={handleClose}>X</span>
      <ul>
        <li className="subMenu navItem">
          <a href="/">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <li className="navItem">
          <a href="/">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li className="navItem">
          <a href="/">Mission</a>
        </li>
        <li className="subMenu navItem">
          <a href="/">About us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default PhoneNavigation;
```

And the following CSS will make it work :

```
.side_bar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: brown;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  // transition applies to every render, i.e., adding and removing any class from 
  // the element
  transition : all 2s ease;
  // place it initially at -100%
  transform : translate(-100%);
}
.show_side_bar {
  // when this class is active, sidebar will be visible
  transform : translate(0);
}
```

Comment: First thank you for your insight. The feature works good however how should I do to be able to see better the sidebar coming because actually is still too fast ? @Mitul Garg

Comment: You can increase the transition duration from 2s to maybe 5s or as much as you like it. @Mugi

Comment: I already test it but unfortunately, it didn't work. The feature works well but it still shows too fast even if I increase the duration, the same happens. How can that be? @Mitul Garg

Comment: Maybe some other class or global styling is affecting it. But the same method has worked for me in all my projects. @Mugi